# If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, and the index of $K$ in $G$ finite, then $[ H : H \cap K ] \leq [G:K]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on this problem and may have found a solution, but I have a step which is not rigorous enough.

**My answer**: Since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, we know that $$|HK|\cdot |H \cap K|=|H|\cdot |K|$$ 
$$\frac{|HK|}{|K|}=\frac{|H|}{|H \cap K|}$$
Since $K$ is a subgroup of $HK$, and $H \cap K$ a subgroup of $H$:
$$[H:H \cap K]=[HK:K]\stackrel{(*)}{=} [HK:G][G:K]\leq[G:K]$$

**My questions**: Does the step $(*)$ hold? If $G \neq HK$ is $[HK:G]$ well defined? Can we also conclude that there is equality iff $HK = G$?

Comment: Notice that it is not assumed in this question that $G$ is finite, only that $|G:K|$ is finite. Your proposed solution works only for finite groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think a correct way to solve it is showing that the homomorphism $H/H\cap K \rightarrow G/K$ is injective.

Comment: That only works if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, but the approach does work. You can just prove the map is injective. It is not a group homomorphism.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right, thank you for your help.

Comment: For arbitrary subgroups, $HK$ need not be a group/subgroup at all! So you cannot say “Since $K$ is a subgroup of $HK$”, as that may not make sense.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $HK$ would have been a subgroup of $G$ if either $K$ or $H$ was normal in $G$ right?

Comment: @NotAbelianGroup: Yes; that is sufficient (but not necessary). $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH$ as sets. This holds when either of them is normal (e.g., if $H$ is normal, then for any $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, we have $hk = k(k^{-1}hk)\in KH$, so $HK\subseteq KH$, and $kh = (khk^{-1})k\in HK$, so $KH\subseteq HK$. However, it is possible for $HK=KH$ to hold even if neither $H$ nor $K$ are normal. For example, in $D_8=\langle r,s\mid r^4=s^2=1, sr=r^3s\rangle$, take $K=\langle s\rangle$ and $H=\langle r^2s\rangle$. Neither is normal, but their product is a subgroup.